# line integral explanation

Tags: complex-analysis

## I asked this on the calculus tag but I didn't get any good answers so I decided to ask it here. It is actually is related to complex analysis because I need to understand the line integral before I can understand greene's theorem. thanks a lot.

I am reading "Advanced Calculus" by David Widder. In chapter 7, "Line and Surface Integrals", he defines the following:

$x_{0} = \phi(a), y_{0} = \psi(a), x_{1} = \phi(b), y_{1} = \psi(b)$   and the line integral goes along the curve $\Gamma$.

But then, later on page, (219), he defines a theorem where he assumes that
A) $\Gamma$ is a regular curve.
B) $f(x,y) \in C$ on $\Gamma$ and C)
$\int_\Gamma f(x,y) \,dx$ and $\int_\Gamma f(x,y) \,dy$ exist.

He then states that "by the law of the mean",

$$ \int_\Gamma f(x,y) \, dx = \lim_{\|\triangle\|\to 0}    
\sum_{i=1}^n f(\phi(t_i), \psi(t_i)) \phi^\prime(t_i^{\prime})(t_i - t_{i-1})$$

The norm $\|\triangle\|$ is the smallest subdivision similar to the sub-division with reimann integrals.

I think that know what the law of the mean is but can someone explain how above is obtained.

My understanding is that the law of the mean for integrals says that if you have a function $f$ that has endpoints and $a$ and $b$ then the law states that

$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) = f^{*}(c) (b - a)\text{ for some  } c \in (a,b) $

So, in this sense $f^{*}(c)$ is the average value of the function. But I don't see how he goes from the law of the mean for integrals to that more complex statement. There is some stuff at the beginning of the page that I can add if this question doesn't seem to make any sense. Thanks a lot. Even a reference is fine.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811743/questions-about-the-line-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line integral is defined in terms of the sum $\sum f(\textbf{r}(t_i))\Delta$ where

$$\Delta = |\textbf{r}(t_i+\Delta t)-\textbf{r}(t_i)|$$

The mean value theorem tells you that

$$ |\textbf{r}(t_i+\Delta t)-\textbf{r}(t_i)|=|\textbf{r}'(t)|\Delta t $$

for some $t\in(t_i,t_i+\Delta t)$. In other words, the MVT is required to bring the derivative in because $\Delta t$ is finite (since we take the limit at a later stage).

If $\Delta t$ is small enough then $|\textbf{r}'(t)|\approx |\textbf{r}'(t_i)|$ and the rest follows easily.

Comment: thanks to both of you. I'll read  both of the comments carefully and then most likely check the answer.